# Property autocapitalization in maven

Tags: maven

I have a maven project that requires a property to be set at the command line(-Dmy.property=val).
What I need to do is to convert that string into all caps since that property is
used for string replacement in a number of files through the maven-resources-plugin. 
What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The groovy plugin could be used. The following configures it to run at the beginning of the Maven build process:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                  </goals>
                   <configuration>
                      <source>
                      import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

                      project.properties["my.property"] = StringUtils.upperCase(project.properties["my.property"]) 
                     </source>
                 </configuration>
             </execution>
          </executions>
     </plugin>
```

Answer (score 7):

With following code, `MY_PROPERTIES` equals to uppercased value of `my.properties`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.12</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>properties-to-uppercase</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>regex-property</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <name>MY_PROPERTY</name>
        <regex>.*</regex>
        <value>${my.property}</value>
        <replacement>$0</replacement>
        <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
        <toUpperCase>true</toUpperCase>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it does not require any code, just another plugin.