# how do i create derived required properties for maven archetypes during generation

Tags: maven, groovy, archetypes, gmaven

I need to provide derivative custom required properties for during archetype:generation when using an archetype. Maven already supports custom required properties that derive from buit-in properties like artifactId and rootArtifactId. But due to some long-standing evaluation ordering issues, it is not possible to reliably derive from custom properties.

I found a solution that might work, using the groovy maven plug-in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521860/property-autocapitalization-in-maven).

The problem with that proposed solution is that the initialization phase does not apply for non-POM uses like archetype generation. My question is how can I use the groovy maven plugin during archetype:generate? I cannot seem to get it to be invoked. I cannot figure out what phase value to use.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I've a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33140688/how-to-hook-into-maven-archetype-code-generation).

Comment: No, unfortunately. I got pulled into another direction and this got put on the shelf. I found some devs who submitted fixes for managing the dependencies between properties. I'm guessing they never got merged into master.